# Set `get_absolute_url` in Django auth

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-urls, django-authentication

I'm using Django's built-in auth model.

How can I set `get_absolute_url` without substituting the entire auth model with a custom auth model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to substitute the user model. But you can simply inherit from `AbstractUser`, which defines all the fields for you already, so that you only need to override the method you want:

```
class MyUser(AbstractUser):
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return ...
```

And then just do `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'my_app.MyUser'` in settings.py, and you're good to go.

Comment: Thank you. Can I do the same with the built-in model `Group`?

Answer (score -2):

You can inherit from the built-in model, `User` for example.

```
class Author(User):
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return what_you_want
```

## update

My first answer was just like the accepted one, but after communicate with the one who asked question, I did some change. But why am I keep getting vote down? Please see the comment first.

Comment: But wont I have to swap the built-in model in order to use this model? I want to use `{{ author.get_absolute_url }}` etc. everywhere in my templates where I have referenced the user model.

Comment: Then I suggest you use the `OneToOneField`, so you can use it like `User.author.get_absolute_url`

Comment: But I have many different models all referencing the user model, so I don't want to create a `get_absolute_url` method in all models.

Comment: You can define a Model like I did in my answer, and all the `many different models` can now referencing the new Model. So you don't need to create a `get_absolute_url` method in all models but only one.